# Call to a member function touch() on integer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i'm getting below **error**

> Call to a member function touch() on integer

What i'm trying to do is on every record `update` i want to change the `update_at` field to `current` `timestamp`

**here is my code:**

```
 $bool = \App\new_customer::where('id',$customerId)->update(['priority'=>'readyForQuotation'])->touch();
```

Answer (score 2):

`update()` executes the query and returns a number of updated rows. So, you need to remove the `->touch()`:

```
\App\new_customer::where('id',$customerId)->update(['priority'=>'readyForQuotation']);
```

If you need to update some data and `updated_at`, do this:

```
$customer = \App\new_customer::find($customerId);
$customer->priority = 'readyForQuotation';
$customer->save();
```

Or you `update()`:

```
\App\new_customer::find($customerId)->update(['priority' => 'readyForQuotation']);
```

If you only need to update `updated_at`, use the `touch()` method like this:

```
\App\new_customer::find($customerId)->touch();
```

Comment: i have used this but it is not updating my `updated_at` to the current `timestamp`

Comment: @EaB I've updated my answer with a couple of other solutions.

Comment: but the above solution is changing both the fields to `current timestamp` **BUT** i want only `updated_at` to be changed to `current timestamp`

Comment: @EaB I'm sorry, but it's not clear. What are both fields you talking about?

Comment: it is `created_at` and `updated_at` The default fields of laravel

Comment: @EaB `created_at` will not be updated here. Sounds like you're creating a new row instead of updating an existing one. Please show the code if you'll not be able to solve this by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try `save()` instead of `touch()`. You can do it with your current code (just avoid the `touch()`) but for further maintenances you should just overwrite the desired field of the retrieved model and call the save function. This will improve readability for foreign devs because you can see the changes directly.

Have a look at [this article](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-touch-for-models-and-their-relationships/) for further informations